# Clean install of Kubernetes on Raspberry Pi doesn't work

Tags: kubernetes, etcd, containerd

I'm trying to do a clean install of Kubernetes 1.23.x on a cluster of four Raspberry Pis, each running the x64 version of Raspberry Pi OS, however I am running into a major snag as soon as I try and run `kubeadm init` on the master node (before even attempting to get the other nodes to join). Namely: just five minutes after calling `kubeadm init` on the master node, the cluster stops working. In fact, it never really works to begin with. At first the server responds saying the node is NotReady, but then after 5 minutes it stops responding altogether.

So here's what I did, and what I saw: I installed containerd and kubeadm. Then I run the following command on the master node to try and start Kubernetes:

```
sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 \
    --token-ttl=0 --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.1.194
```

After running that command, and subsequently copying the /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf file to ~/.kube/config, I am able to run the following command:

```
$ kubectl get nodes

NAME           STATUS     ROLES                  AGE     VERSION
k8s-master-1   NotReady   control-plane,master   3m36s   v1.23.4
```

And it will continue to show a NotReady status for about 5 minutes, after which point the same command yields a very different result:

```
$ kubectl get nodes

The connection to the server 192.168.1.194:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, but it is very consistent. I have tried a few times now to `kubeadm reset` and then `kubeadm init` again, and the connection timeout always happens at the 5-minute mark. So the last time I tried to do this, I decided to tail all the log files under `/var/log/containers/`. After the 5-minute mark, it is repeatedly logging some variation of a connection error to 127.0.0.1:2379. For example:

> 2022-03-09T19:30:29.307156643-06:00 stderr F W0310 01:30:29.306871 1 clientconn.go:1331] [core] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {127.0.0.1:2379 127.0.0.1 0 }. Err: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...

From Googling, it appears that etcd is running on that port, but then at the 5-minute mark, a bunch of services (including etcd) start shutting down. I've uploaded the full logs from the time `kubeadm init` runs, up until prior to the dreaded 5-minute mark, [as a Gist](https://gist.github.com/soapergem/fd71b313473aa366e5bb44acdaccaab4).

I have already checked that all the ports are open, too. (They are.) During those first five minutes, I can telnet to local port 2379. Why won't Kubernetes start on my Pi? What am I missing?

**UPDATE:** As requested, I can provide a few more details. I saw a post recommending setting the value of `--apiserver-advertise-address` to `0.0.0.0` instead of the direct IP, so I tried that but it seemed to make no difference. I tried running `systemctl status kubelet` which shows that the kubelet service is "active" during that initial 5 minute period.

I also ran `kubectl describe node k8s-master-1`, which shows four events in this sequence:

1. KubeletHasSufficientMemory
2. KubeletHasNoDiskPressure
3. KubeletHasSufficientPID
4. KubeletNotReady

That last event is accompanied by this message: "container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:Network plugin returns error: cni plugin not initialized." So that got me thinking. I had been waiting for the Node to come up as Ready before installing Flannel (aka the CNI plugin), but this time I decided to try installing Flannel during that initial 5 minute period, using this command:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flannel-io/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
```

And to my great surprise, that worked! Well, sort of. The master node did eventually start reporting a "Ready" status. And I noticed that all my pods came up with the notable exception of the coredns pods. However, after a short while, the kube-proxy pod (in the kube-system namespace) dies and gets stuck in a CrashLoopBackoff, and then later still the kube-controller-manager and kube-scheduler pods similarly enter a CrashLoopBackoff. Then, this time, after about 15 minutes, the whole cluster died again as before (meaning I got the same 'connection to the server was refused' message). So I feel like I'm a little bit closer, but also still a long ways away from getting this working.

**SECOND UPDATE:** A couple of things: it seems that when I install the flannel CNI plugin, coredns is either not included or doesn't work. But when I install weave works CNI then it at least tries to spin up coredns, although unfortunately those pods get stuck in ContainerCreating and never actually activate. So as requested, I am providing a number of additional logs. They're long enough to warrant uploading them separately so here's a [link to a Gist](https://gist.github.com/soapergem/4a67818bd1d5a9625ab3eb95d9fae5b4) containing four logs:

1. Running `kubectl -n kube-system logs pod/coredns-...`
2. Running `kubectl -n kube-system logs pod/kube-controller-manager-k8s-master-1`
3. Running `kubectl -n kube-system logs pod/kube-proxy-...`
4. Running `kubectl describe node k8s-master-1`

Note that before everything dies, the kube-controller-manager-... pod starts up but soon finds itself in a CrashLoopBackoff. While the coredns pods never start up successfully at all.

Comment: What does dmesg or syslog show?

Comment: Run `kubectl describe node nodename` to check why the node is NotReady. 
Check `systemctl status kubelet` and `journalctl -u kubelet`. Did you turn off the swap?

Comment: @mozello I updated my original post with more details per your recommendations.

Comment: Are coredns pods in 'Pending' state? Check if there is any 'taint' when you run 'kubectl describe node'.

Comment: Also, please add the logs from the kube-proxy pod `kubectl -n kube-system logs kube-proxy-...`

Comment: @mozello thanks for following up with me and apologies on the long delay. I've edited my original post to add a bunch of additional logs in a Gist link at the end. I really appreciate you looking at this!